# Failing test running successful in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, webforms, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms project which is hosted on a Azure DevOps Repository. The Source Control is TFS.

I Created a continuous integration Pipeline in Azure Devops for the Repository. 
Here is a Image of the Pipeline:

[image]

All the Task from the Pipeline are running correctly beside the `VSTest-TestAssemblies` Task.
My NUnit Test is failing in my local Visual Studio, as it should:

[image]

But when running my CI, it tells my that no test failed:
[image]

Here you can see my settings and the path to my tests of the `VSTest-TestAssemblies` Task:
[image]

This is what the Folder Structure of my Project looks like:

```
NR.TestAutomation
- NR.TestAutomation
- NR.TestAutomation.Tests
  - bin
  - obj
  - DemoTests.cs
  - NR.TestAutomation.Tests.csproj
- packages
- NR.TestsAutomation.sln
```

The Output of the CI Run tells me, that the folder exist and it even finds the test:

```
Source filter: **/*Tests/*.cs
SystemVssConnection exists true

vstest.console.exe "D:\a\9\s\NR.TestAutomation.Tests\DemoTests.cs"
```

**Why are my failing tests not failing inside the Azure DevOps Pipeline?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the (output of the) **TestProject** to run, not the individual files that contain a test. The test runner cannot execute a `.cs file`.
So in short; the failing test doesn't run successful in an Azure DevOps pipeline... it *doesn't run in the pipeline at all*.

> **Test files**
>   Run tests from the specified files. Ordered tests and webtests can be run by specifying the `.orderedtest` and `.webtest` files respectively. To run `.webtest`, Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 or higher is needed. The file paths are relative to the search folder. Supports multiple lines of minimatch patterns.

Source [Visual Studio Test task - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments)

Possibly interesting as well: more info on [File matching patterns reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops)

**EDIT:**

> what would be the proper Source Path to my tests?

Of course that depends on the name of your test project. Looking at your screenshots, you could use `**/*.Tests.dll`. This recursively matches all the assemblies where the name ends with `.Tests.dll`.
Since your project's name is `NR.TestAutomation.Tests`, the assembly should be named `NR.TestAutomation.Tests.dll` so it will match. It's also ready for future additions of test projects, as long as their name ends with `.Tests`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would be the proper Source Path to my tests?